# Getting 400 error in a Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

This is my spring-mvc project and I am trying to login but I am not able to do that. I have included all the files which I have created.

So this is my jsp form below.

```
      <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
            <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"prefix="spring"%>
            <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
            <%@ page session="false" %>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Employee Page</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form action="reg.htm" method="get">
                Employee name:  <input type="text" name="ename"/>
                Employee ID:  <input type="text" name="empno"/>
                Employee job:  <input type="text" name="job"/>
                <input type="submit" value="success"/>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

This is my controller class below.

```
        package com.SpringMvcHello.Controller;

        import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

        import com.ycs.bean.Employee;


        @Controller
        public class RegistrationController {


            @RequestMapping(value="/reg.htm", method= RequestMethod.GET)
            public ModelAndView sayHello(@ModelAttribute("e")Employee emp){
                ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("login1");
                String ename=emp.getEname();
                System.out.println("ename ="+ename);
                return model;

            }


        }
```

This is my web.xml file below.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
             xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
            <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->



         <context:component-scan base-package="com.SpringMvcHello.Controller"/>

           <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
              <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
              <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
           </bean>

            <bean name="e" class="com.ycs.bean.Employee"/>

            <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>



        </beans>
```

This is my dispatchers-servlet to configure my dispatcher servlet.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
          <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
          <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
           </welcome-file-list>




        <!-- Dispatcher Servlet configuration -->


           <servlet>
              <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
              <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
              <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
           </servlet>
           <servlet-mapping>
              <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
              <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> 
           </servlet-mapping>


         <!--   Session configuration -->

             <session-config>
                <session-timeout>
                    30
                </session-timeout>
            </session-config>

        </web-app>
```

This is view part

```
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>
        hello ${e.ename}</h1>  
        Your ID is : ${e.empno}
        Your Name is : ${e.ename}
        Job is : ${e.job}

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your login page you have a form with the data that you want send through the POST method to be evaluated and return your login session right?.

Then:

```
<form action="reg.htm" method="POST">
                Employee name:  <input type="text" name="ename"/>
                Employee ID:  <input type="text" name="empno"/>
                Employee job:  <input type="text" name="job"/>
                <input type="submit" value="success"/>
</form>
```

then in your controller you need to declare the method that go to handle it

```
@Controller
        public class RegistrationController {


            @RequestMapping(value="/reg.htm", method= RequestMethod.POST)
            public ModelAndView sayHello(@ModelAttribute("e")Employee emp){
                //Here you don't need to set a view, you can redirect to another view with the right object model.
                ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("redirect:index");
                String ename=emp.getEname();
                //Here you can add directly you Employee object to your model
                model.addAttribute("emp", emp);
                System.out.println("ename ="+ename);
                return model;

            }


}
```

then in your index view you can call you emp object with Spring Expression Language (SPEL) like this:

```
<div>My Employee name: ${emp.ename}</div>
```

Comment: but i am using get

Comment: With get method in your form you are not sending data to your controller you only are requesting data.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the form to spring form like this:

```
<form:form action="reg.htm" modelAttribute="e">
            Employee name:  <form:input type="text" name="ename"path="ename"/>
            Employee ID:  <form:input type="text" name="empno"path="empno"/>
            Employee job:  <form:input type="text" name="job" path="job"/>
            <input type="submit" value="success"/>
</form:form>
```